# Magento 2: cron not executing properly

Tags: magento2, sales-order, cron

I have created a custom module which will read order edi files and import orders in magento. To run this in scheduled basis, I have written cron for this job.

```
<job name="import_order_edi" instance="Singh\Import\Cron\OrderImport" method="execute">
        <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
</job>
```

in my OrderImport.php file I am calling the execute method of main controller class where code to create order is written.

```
$this->_order->execute();
```

$this->_order is the object of main controller class where code to  read file and create order is written.
But when I run the cron, the **memory** of server reaches to **97** and **CPU to 99%**, and cron stops,  with no orders imported in magento.
But when I run this controller from web-browser, order got created.
Why my cron stops executing ? But through web-browser its working?

Comment: How about your issue?

Comment: I checked with my issue, and found the bug. There was some corrupt data for customer, due to which this error was coming

Comment: You can call the execute method of one controller directly in your cron job?

Comment: Yes I am calling the execute method of one controller directly in my cron job, because I am not finding any other way.And it is working.